# Search for Element in binary tree

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

We have this tree:

```
data Bintree a = Empty | Fork a (Bintree a) (Bintree a) deriving Show
data Edge = Left | Right deriving Show
type Node = [Edge]
```

I should search for an element in it. If I find it, I return Just Node. If not, I return Nothing. The tree is not ordered.

```
search :: Eq a => a -> Bintree a -> Maybe Node
```

The search function should look like this.

Comment: what should `search 1 (Fork 1 Empty Empty)` return?

Comment: probably `Just []`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem right. thanks.

Comment: What if the element appears twice (or more)?

Answer (score 3):

```
search :: Eq a => a -> Bintree a -> Maybe [Edge]
search a Empty = Nothing
search a (Fork b lt rt) = (guard (a==b) >> pure [])
                        <|> (Left  :) <$> search a lt
                        <|> (Right :) <$> search a rt
```

should do the trick. Performs left-biased depth-first search, returning the path to the first matching value, if any.

This uses `Just` as a Functor, as an Applicative, as Alternative, a Monad and as a MonadPlus, using data type-encoded behavior to spare us having to write some mundane code ourselves.

Comment: Can you explain which part is using the `MonadPlus` a little bit more? I do understand `<$>` for functor, `<|>` for alternative and `guard` for monad.

Comment: @wizzup `guard :: MonadPlus m => Bool -> m ()`.